# iPad multitasking activate/deactivate constraints according to autolayout in storyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, autolayout, multitasking

During the app runtime, I sometimes change `active` property of some constraints that were set up in the storyboard to hide/show some views.

Everything works fine but if app transition from one size to another (changes traits for example when the user resizes the app on iPad splitview (two apps on screen)) all the constraints return to their initial state from the storyboard. (Happens when app takes half of the screen and is resized to take more than 50% of the screen. iOS 11)

E.g. if in storyboard the constraint is active and later on during runtime, I deactivate it, after stretching the app (when app is a part of splitview on iPad) it activates again.

Is it a bug or feature? How to prevent this from happening? What is the best callback method to activate/deactivate those constraints again?

Comment: Check following answer the link in the answer should give you more details about this kind of implementation

Comment: @HarshalBhavsar thanks, by now I find my solution better.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an option to create those modifiable constraints in code instead of inside a storyboard, I think it's the best solution. If not, use methods below.

---

I decided to use `traitCollectionDidChange:` method inside my view controller. Constraints are not changed at the time of the call to this method so I created a flag that will be used in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method that is called after traits collection change. 
When `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called constraints are already changed, so we can reconfigure them as needed.

```
- (void)traitCollectionDidChange:(UITraitCollection *)previousTraitCollection {
    [super traitCollectionDidChange:previousTraitCollection];
    if (previousTraitCollection) _traitsCollectionDidChange = YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    if (_traitsCollectionDidChange) {
        _traitsCollectionDidChange = NO;

        // reconfigure your constraints
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the following document from apple

[Adopting Multitasking Enhancements on iPad](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/QuickStartForSlideOverAndSplitView.html)

When the user moves the divider, the system calls your app delegate object with the `applicationWillResignActive:` protocol method.

Also i found one more point as follows

> Respond to trait collection and size changes by implementing methods
>   in the `UITraitEnvironment` and `UIContentContainer` protocols.

Is the method where you will get triggered when user try to change the size

I will suggest to go through the document for more details on this.

Comment: Thanks for try) I think it's a bad design to use `applicationWillResignActive:` in this case because this callback is not related to size-class changes and is called everytime the user gets a system dialog or leaves the app.

Comment: Added more data in answer please check

Comment: Thanks, I've already solved the problem that way, see my answer

Comment: Glat you got the solution